# Converter varchar em date no SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Tem como converter datas em **varchar** para **date**.
Estou tendo dificuldades em realizar buscas entre datas, devido a esta discrepância no banco de dados onde realizo a consulta.

Quando insiro minha linha de código:

```
    select *
    from TAB_FATURAMENTO
    where cd_cliente like '%'
    and dt_item between '15/05/2017' and '31/05/2017';
```

O resultado da minha busca me retorna valores de datas anteriores ao meu range.

Comment: Se entendi corretamente, a coluna `dt_item` é do tipo varchar, certo?

Comment: Se sua data estiver como varchar, primeiro você tem que converter todas para o formato do date (xx/xx/xxxx -> xxxx-xx-xx) e em seguida converter o tipo do campo para date.

Comment: Isso mesmo @Renan, meu campo `dt_item` está como varchar... e por conta disso, não consigo realizar minha busca corretamente.

Comment: @TonyAnderson, se a coluna dt_item está como varchar, qual é o formato de armazenamento: dd/mm/aaaa? aaaammdd? outro? // O que pretende com a restrição {WHERE cd_cliente like '%'} ?

Comment: @JoséDiz, os valores são armazenados como `dd/mm/aaaa` // O {WHERE cd_cliente like '%'}, busca todos os clientes.

Comment: @TonyAnderson: Como a data está armazenada em coluna do tipo caractere e no formato dd/mm/aaaa, é necessário que, na cláusula WHERE, o conteúdo da coluna seja convertido para outro formato que se possa fazer a comparação direta de intervalos de data. Uma opção é converter para o tipo de dados `date` antes de comparar com os limites, também como `date`.  //  Se é para listar todos os clientes, sugiro que retire então a restrição `cd_cliente like '%'` da cláusula WHERE.

Comment: @TonyAnderson Não é uma boa ideia alterar a pergunta tão radicalmente depois de já ter recebido tantas respostas. Se você agora precisa de algo para Firebird, abra uma nova pergunta. Seria injusto invalidar a resposta de todo mundo porque você decidiu agora alterar a tag da pergunta.

Comment: @jbueno, conforme você havia sugerido, fiz uma nova pergunta: `Como converter datas em varchar para date no SQL 'Firebird'?`.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 15):

Se a sua coluna `dt_item` estiver como `varchar` no formato `dd/MM/yyyy`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TAB_FATURAMENTO
 WHERE cd_cliente LIKE '%'
   AND CONVERT(DATE, dt_item, 103) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, '15/05/2017', 103) AND CONVERT(DATE, '31/05/2017', 103);
```

Assim você transformará as 3 partes em data e conseguirá realizar a comparação de forma correta.

No link abaixo [**CAST e CONVERT (Transact-SQL) - Estilos de data e hora**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_4) da documentação você pode conferir os códigos correspondentes à conversões de data;

Conversões disponíveis:

```
╔═════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Sem século (AA) ║ Com século (aaaa) ║ Standard                          ║ Entrada/saída (3)                      ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 0 ou 100 (1,2)    ║ Padrão para datetime e            ║ mês dd aaaa hh:miAM (ou PM)            ║
║                 ║                   ║ smalldatetime                     ║                                        ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1               ║ 101               ║ EUA                               ║ 1 = mm/dd/aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 101 = mm/dd/aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 3               ║ 103               ║ Britânico/francês                 ║ 3 = dd/mm/aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 103 = dd/mm/aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 4               ║ 104               ║ Alemão                            ║ 4 = dd.mm.aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 104 = dd.mm.aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 5               ║ 105               ║ Italiano                          ║ 5 = dd-mm-aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 105 = dd-mm-aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 6               ║ 106 (1)           ║ -                                 ║ 6 = dd mês aa                          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 106 = dd mês aaaa                      ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 7               ║ 107 (1)           ║ -                                 ║ 7 = Mês dd, aa                         ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 107 = Mês dd, aaaa                     ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 8               ║ 108               ║ -                                 ║ hh:mi:ss                               ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 9 ou 109          ║ Padrão + milissegundos            ║ mês dd aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (ou PM)     ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 10              ║ 110               ║ EUA                               ║ 10 = mm-dd-aa                          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 110 = mm-dd-aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 11              ║ 111               ║ JAPÃO                             ║ 11 = aa/mm/dd                          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 111 = aaaa/mm/dd                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 12              ║ 112               ║ ISO                               ║ 12 = aammdd                            ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 112 = aaaammdd                         ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 13 ou 113         ║ Padrão Europa + milissegundos     ║ dd mês aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmm (24h)         ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 14              ║ 114               ║ -                                 ║ hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)                      ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 20 or 120 (2)     ║ ODBC canônico                     ║ aaaa-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)               ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 21 or 121 (2)     ║ ODBC canônico (com milissegundos) ║ aaaa-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)               ║
║                 ║                   ║ padrão para hora, data, datetime2 ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║ e datetimeoffset                  ║                                        ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 126 (4)           ║ ISO8601                           ║ aaaa-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (sem espaços)  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ Observação: Quando o valor de          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos (mmm) for 0, o valor de  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos não é exibido. Por       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ exemplo, o valor                       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ '2012-11-07T18:26:20.000' é exibido    ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ como '2012-11-07T18:26:20'.            ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 127(6, 7)         ║ ISO8601 com fuso horário Z.       ║ aaaa-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ (sem espaços) ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ Observação: Quando o valor de          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos (mmm) for 0, o valor de  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos não é exibido. Por       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ exemplo, o valor                       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ '2012-11-07T18:26:20.000' é exibido    ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ como '2012-11-07T18:26:20'.            ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 130 (1, 2)        ║ Hijri (5)                         ║ dd mmm aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmmAM             ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ Neste estilo, mon representa uma       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ representação unicode Hijri de vários  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ tokens do nome completo do mês. Este   ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ valor não será renderizado corretamente║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ em uma instalação US padrão do SSMS.   ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 131 (2)           ║ Hijri (5)                         ║ dd/mm/aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmmAM              ║
╚═════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

- (1) esses valores de estilo retornam resultados não determinísticos. Incluem todos os estilos (aa) (sem século) e um subconjunto de estilos (aaaa) (com século).
- (2) Os valores padrão (style0 or 100, 9 or 109, 13 or 113, 20 or 120, and 21 or 121) sempre retornam o século (yyyy).
- (3) entrada quando você converte em datetime; saída quando você converter dados de caractere.
- (4) projetado para uso de XML. Para conversão de datetime ou smalldatetime dados de caracteres de formato de saída é conforme descrito na tabela anterior.
- (5) Hijri é um sistema de calendário com muitas variações. SQL Server usa o algoritmo kuwaitiano.

Answer (score 3):

Use o [**CONVERT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select *
from TAB_FATURAMENTO
where cd_cliente like '%'
and dt_item between CONVERT(varchar(10), '15/05/2017', 103) and CONVERT(varchar(10), '31/05/2017', 103);
```

O valor **103** define que a string de data está no formato **dd/mm/aaaa**.

Comment: utilizei o seu select, @George Wurthmann. Porém, ocorreu o seguinte erro: `ISC ERROR CODE:335544569

ISC ERROR MESSAGE:
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 4, column 29
varchar

Statement: select *
from TAB_FATURAMENTO
where cd_cliente like '%'
and dt_item between CONVERT(varchar, '15/05/2017', 103) and CONVERT(varchar, '31/05/2017', 103)`

Comment: @TonyAnderson, substitua o varchar do convert para char(10), se der certo edito a resposta. Detalhe: você tem certeza que dt_item é varchar??

Comment: Fiz uma pequena edição na resposta também mudando `varchar` para `varchar(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver no SQL e considerando que o campo dt_item é do tipo date, para realizar a consulta você pode fazer assim:

```
select *
    from TAB_FATURAMENTO
    where cd_cliente like '%'
    and dt_item between '2017-05-15' and '2017-05-31';
```

Abs.

Comment: O campo dt_item dele não é date time, isso que gerou a dúvida dele. O select que você colocou é exatamente igual ao dele.

Comment: No meu select eu uso o padrão do SQL Server que é yyyy-MM-dd e nestes casos da diferença em relação ao formato que ele usou.

Comment: Ah sim, mas ainda assim é necessário um cast. A não ser que a coluna dele esteja em date time e ele não saiba. hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TAB_FATURAMENTO
where cd_cliente like '%'
and dt_item between LEFT(TAB_FATURAMENTO.data, 10) >='2017-05-15' And
                    LEFT(TAB_FATURAMENTO.data, 10)  <='31/05/2017'
```

penso que esta é a maneira mais correcta de converter e comparar tente

Answer (score 0):

Se a coluna DT_ITEM for do tipo data (DATE ou DATETIME) e você quer converter string em data utilize o seguinte:

```
    select *
from TAB_FATURAMENTO
where cd_cliente like '%'
and dt_item between convert(DATETIME, '2017-05-01', 103) and convert(DATETIME, '2017-05-31', 102)
```

Comment: Sua `query` retorna o erro `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Answer (score -1):

Após analise minuciosa das tabelas do banco, descobrimos (meu gerente e eu), que o problema está no próprio campo, o mesmo não esta reconhecendo os meios de conversão.

Sendo assim, a forma que encontramos para fazer tais comparações entre as datas foi esta:

```
select *
from TAB_FATURAMENTO
where (substring(dt_item from 1 for 2) between substring('15/05/2017' from 1 for 2) and substring('31/05/2017' from 1 for 2) )
and (substring(dt_item from 4 for 2) between substring('15/05/2017' from 4 for 2) and substring('31/05/2017' from 4 for 2) )
and (substring(dt_item from 7 for 4) between substring('15/05/2017' from 7 for 4) and substring('31/05/2017' from 7 for 4) )
order by dt_item`
```

Não é, visualmente muito bonito, mas foi o que resolveu nosso problema.

Desde já agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Isso tem uma performance muito ruim. As respostas com mais votos são alternativas melhores. Mas melhor do que tudo isso seria alterar a coluna para guardar datas ao invés de textos.

Comment: @TonyAnderson: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: MariaDB? Oracle Database? outro? //   A construção que postou como solução não é aceita no SQL Server.

Comment: @JoséDiz, é o Firebird. O problema todo, é que este banco de dados já nos foi passado assim, e há um programa em Delphi associado ao mesmo.
Já tentamos mudar algumas outras tabelas, mas tivemos muitos problemas com isso.

Comment: @TonyAnderson as soluções dadas não funcionaram por isso, nas tags está SQL server e não Firebird.

Comment: Já realizei a correção, me desculpem por isso, não atentei na hora de postar a pergunta.

Comment: @TonyAnderson: Independente de qual seja o gerenciador de banco de dados, a solução que postou somente será correta se os valores de mês e ano forem os mesmos. // Se o valor de dt_item for 25/12/2016 e o período for de 20/12/2016 a 10/1/2017, o valor de dt_item está no período, certo? Afinal o dia 25/12/2016 está entre 20/12/2016 e 10/1/2017. Entretanto, o código que postou indicará que não. // Observou que substring('15/05/2017' from 1 for 2) é a mesma coisa que '15'?  // SUGESTÃO: crie outro tópico, com conteúdo idêntico a este, mas informando firebird como gerenciador.

Comment: Grato pela sugestão, @JoséDiz, farei isso.